# Mongoose - 5.3.4 - Prevent cast to ObjectId for query with string

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am attempting to `findOneAndUpdate`a string-based token on a User model. And
I receive the error:

```
Cast to ObjectId failed for value "{ passwordResetToken: '4946d72f19b9649d3f306a0f5be59005c884ae453fc049c7',
  passwordResetExpires: { '$gt': 1543196590882 } }" at path "_id" for model "User"
```

the **document** is stored like so:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5bfb424da0cc0923f05b67f1"
    },
    "local": {
        "email": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
        "password": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
    },
    "isVerified": false,
    "method": "local",
    "__v": 0,
    "passwordResetExpires": {
        "$date": "2018-11-26T02:41:17.851Z"
    },
    "passwordResetToken": "4946d72f19b9649d3f306a0f5be59005c884ae453fc049c7"
}
```

and I **query** the document like so:

```
req.params.token = "4946d72f19b9649d3f306a0f5be59005c884ae453fc049c7"


User.findByIdAndUpdate({
      'passwordResetToken': req.params.token,
      'passwordResetExpires': { $gt: Date.now() }
    }, 
    {
      'local.password'        : req.body.password,
      'passwordResetExpires'  : null,
      'passwordResetToken'    : null
    }, {new: true})
    .then(user => {
      res.send(user);
    })
    .catch(err => next(err))
```

This is my current **Schema**:

```
var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  method: {
    type: String,
    enum: ['local', 'google', 'facebook']
  },
  local: {
    email: {
      type: String,
      lowercase: true
    },
    password: String,
  },
  google: {
    id: String,
    email: {
      type: String,
      lowercase: true
    },
    name: String,
    token: String
  },
  facebook: {
    id: String,
    name: String,
    token: String
  },
  isVerified: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false,
    required: true
  },
  passwordResetToken: String,
  passwordResetExpires: Date
});
```

I guess mongoose Is attempting to cast this hex string into a _id value? Is there some way to prevent mongoose from casting the string into an `ObjectId Type`?

Comment: That's `findOneAndUpdate()`. The `findByIdAndUpdate()` is ***specifically*** a shorhand form for `{ _id: idValue }`. You cannot use it for any other form. Even if `_id` in your document is anything other than `ObjectId` ( which is not the case here ), then you use the other method anyway.

Comment: @NeilLunn of course... long day. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In mongoose, if you use `findByIdAndUpdate()`, you have to provide a value that is the objectID. So, in your case, it tries to find an Object ID but cannot and hence you get an error. Something more appropriate to your use case would be `findOneAndUpdate()`. Here, you are free to use other parameters.